# The window would like the X- represents at the same time in two frame buffers

Tags: x11, display, framebuffer, hdmi

I'm using the two frame buffer.

/dev/fb0: 1024x768 (LCD)

/dev/fb1: 1920x1080 (HDMI)

I want to be the same content simultaneously on two frame buffer output.

Is there any way ?